# How to stay connected with friends, family while abroad?

Tags: cellphones, international-travel, communication

How do you stay connected with your friends, colleagues and family while abroad?
I've recently came across such a thing as [TravelSIM](http://www.travelsim.com/) which offers a callback service at quite low prices and to my surprise I found no evidences of mentioning it here on SE.
Calls from Europe seems to be quite cheap in comparison to classic roaming.

Does anybody have experience of using it?

Comment: Have you considered local prepaid SIM? Or using wifi for Skype?

Comment: @Karlson Yes, but this looks quite inconvenient in comparison to a single SIM used worldwidely and requires some googling to find out the most suitable prepaid sim in the destination country. What about Skype, one will anyway require some money on Skype account to call landline phones.

Comment: This question feels a lot like spam

Comment: @Andra, that's what I was a bit afraid of. Any suggestions how make it look better?

Comment: At 85 euros for a starter package, I find this travelsim mightily expensive, even though I'm impressed that in many countries, receiving calls is free (though they don't seem to state what it costs to call a travelsim number, but as travelsims use the Estonia international dialing prefix, I suppose it's the cost of calling Estonia). Also cool: calling from Skype to travelsim is free.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it provides significantly lower prices than roaming in Europe for outgoing calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used callback services years ago. When I was in South Africa a $5 card from http://www.thephonecardstore.ca/ would give me as many hours (12, I think) of talk time to Canada as I would get minutes by just calling the regular way. You can still buy these and they seem to work fine. You can also often get cards at convenience stores but I can't read all the terms and conditions under those cirumstances.

That said, I've been 100% Skype on foreign trips for a long time now.

Comment: +1: Skype ftw. I used callback services within Europe when living in Belgium some years ago, but this option has been fully supplanted by Skype, which also allows showing the environment. Just make sure you stay at a hotel with free internet access.